# Where did XYTools go

Tags: qgis

Where can I find the repository for XYTools plugin? I have tried several repositories and got messages that it was permanently removed!

Comment: this question is better asked in the qgis mailing list

Comment: what version of Qgis u are currently using now?

Answer (score 0):

It is still available for QGIS 1.8.0, in the Official QGIS repository. And it has it's own project pages:

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/xytools

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/xytools/

Last activity seems to have been in January. Unless someone ports it to the new QGIS 2.0 API, you can not access it there.